# What Simulator devices are currently needed to make screenshots for Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

I ask this question as instead of getting to this information quickly I had to search for it in a more complicated manner.

So, what Simulator devices are needed to make screenshots for all resolutions that are now required to publish or update an application in the App Store?

I believe this can be helpful to a lot of developers as the error message while uploading images is not very helpful.

Comment: For the moment, documentation can be found [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of Feb 2023:

- For *iPhone 6.7" Display*, use **iPhone 14 Pro Max**
- For *iPhone 6.5" Display*, use **iPhone 13 Pro Max**
- For *iPhone 5.5" Display*, use **iPhone 8 Plus**
- For *iPad Pro (3rd Gen) 12.9" Display*, use **iPad Pro (12.9-inch)**
- For *iPad Pro (2nd Gen) 12.9" Display*, use **iPad Pro (12.9-inch)**

(So, for the iPads, you only need one device.)

Here's how it looks like in practice.

[image: Screenshot showing the selection of devices in Simulator File menu]

[image: Screenshot showing all the Simulator devices you'll need for App Store Connect]

Have fun!

Comment: After updating to Xcode 14 with iOS 16, I'm not seeing any 5.5 devices - makes sense, as Xcode simulators only seem to support one iOS, and none of the 5.5 devices (for instance iPhone 8 Plus) runs iOS 16. However, 5.5 screenshots are still mandatory for the App store. So how do I create these without a physical iPhone 8 Plus, without the bother to downgrade Xcode?

Comment: Thanks. I've probably looked up this same question for 10 years because Apple can't seem to make this flow developer friendly.

Comment: I struggled to select a 5.5 inch device, until I noticed that even though there is no 5.5 inch device in the `file>open simulator` menu, I can create a 5.5 device from `file>new simulator` menu. So I didn't need to downgrade XCode, @Vering. Hope this helps.

Comment: After adding a new simulator, I also had to go to Manage Run Destinations, select the new simulator I had chosen, and then set "Show run destination" to "Always".

Comment: When capturing simulator screenshot for  "iPhone 8 Plus", # 5.5, the output is  `1125 × 2436`

Comment: The iPhone 15 Pro Max also works for the 6.7" display screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

### iPhone app

- iPhone 6.5-inch (iPhone XS Max / XR): 1242 x 2688 px or 2688 x 1242 px
- iPhone 5.5-inch (iPhone 6/6s/7/8 Plus): 1242 x 2208 px or 2208 x 1242 px

### iPad app

- iPad 12.9-inch (iPad Pro 3rd Gen.): 2048 x 2732 px or 2732 x 2048 px
- iPad 12.9-inch (iPad Pro 2nd Gen.): 2048 x 2732 px or 2732 x 2048 px

I was able to upload the 2nd Gen. "old" screenshots to the newer 3rd Gen. screenshots and they go consistently through review, without any issues.

### Universal app

- iPhone 6.5-inch (iPhone XS Max / XR): 1242 x 2688 px or 2688 x 1242 px
- iPhone 5.5-inch (iPhone 6/6s/7/8 Plus): 1242 x 2208 px or 2208 x 1242 px
- iPad 12.9-inch (iPad Pro 3rd Gen.): 2048 x 2732 px or 2732 x 2048 px
- iPad 12.9-inch (iPad Pro 2nd Gen.): 2048 x 2732 px or 2732 x 2048 px

Comment: I hope the 3rd generation screenshots will also work for the 2nd generation since the 2nd gen is not supported in Simulator anymore.

Comment: @ispiro As long as no obvious elements are on the screenshots, it's fine. I've seen Apple reject screenshots for the iPad 2nd generation, which had the tab bar indicator. You can always add "older" simulators to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

So now in 2019 you need to supply images for 4 devices, for iPhone 6.5 screen you need iPhone XS max simulator and
for iPhone 5.5 you need a iPhone 8 Plus simulator. 
Then you need also iPad Pro second as well as third generation but that is quite obvious.

Answer (score 1):

## OCT 2022 (Xcode 14) - Devices/Simulators for required screenshot sizes

iPhone 6.5-inch: **iPhone 11 Pro Max**

iPhone 5.5-inch: **iPhone 8 Plus**

iPad 12.9-inch: **iPad Pro 3rd Gen**

iPad 12.9-inch: **iPad Pro 2nd Gen**

Pro Tip: If you don't see those devices, you can add them:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs4JI.png

*Apple Reference* https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

Answer (score 1):

To give a more generic answer instead of just updating month-to-month or year to year.

1. Find the device screen sizes required from Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications). (You should just be able to Ctrl/Cmd+F for the screen size.)
2. If the device is not supported on the current OS, check the last supported OS. I used [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history).
3. Download the OS version. Currently you can do this in XCode>Settings>Platforms but maybe this will move in the future.
4. Create an emulated device in Simulator>File>New Simulator.

Notes:

- You'll probably want to select the OS Version first (before the device) in Simulator because if for some reason the OS version is wrong, it will automatically remove/change the value if it isn't supported.
- Currently, if you want to always see the newly created device in XCode's device selection dropdown (in the window header: Runner > 'device name here') if you click on the device ('device name here' part) at the bottom you should see "manage run destinations." In that window there's a simulators tab and after clicking your device you can change the "show run destination" value to "Always."

Answer (score 0):

Use iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) for the iPad screenshots. Should work for both

Answer (score 0):

**July 2023**

Based on [Screenshot specifications](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications):

```
# A list of devices you want to take the screenshots from
devices([
  # iPhone
  "iPhone 14 Pro Max", # 6.7
  "iPhone 14 Plus", # 6.5
  "iPhone 8 Plus", # 5.5
  # iPad
  "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation)", 
  "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)"
])
```

Go to Window (top bar) -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators -> + (bottom left) if a simulator is missing.